# How to check which user has changed their or other user's password?

Tags: linux, syslog, passwd

How can I capture (if there is a log file somewhere) when a user changes their password or another user's password?

I see this log but I can't determine whom change password for user XXXX

Mar 31 12:41:52 UBGGH passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for XXXX

I use centos version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the user `XXXX` changed this password or root did.

If you have `sudo` enabled to allow other users to get root privileges it's possible one of them could have used it to run `passwd` as root. Typically a log message will be written when `sudo` is used, but of course if a user has root privileges they could convceivably remove or otherwise tamper with the log record.

Moving forwards, you can use `lastcomm` or the far more detailed audit subsystem to track what commands are run by which user. For example,

```
lastcomm passwd
passwd                 root     __         0.01 secs Thu Jun  9 07:25
```

Comment: Thanks roaima 
Is there any way to force linux to record like these log event if not use sudo :

Mar 31 12:41:41 UBUNTU sudo: daniel : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/dev ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd root

Comment: @abdkah I've updated my answer for you

Comment: I think I should use audit subsystem . can you help me  a  guide about that